# Python import modules in same directory for Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create a Flask application. I would like to include a separate module in my application to separate logic into distinct units. The separate module is called 'validator' and my current directory structure looks like this:

```
src/
    validation-api/
        __init__.py
        api.py
    validator/
        __init__.py
        validator.py
    validation-form/
        ...
    updater/
        ...
```

My Flask application is in `api.py` and I am trying to do `from validator import ValidationOptions, ValidationResult, ValidationRun` where `ValidationOptions`, `ValidationResult`, and `ValidationRun` are classes in `validator`.

I am getting the error

> ImportError: No module named validator

If I try `from .validator...` or `from ..validator` I get the error

> ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

I don't quite understand how modules and packages work in Python. Any suggestions?

---

Contents of api.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from validator.validator import ValidationOptions, ValidationResult, ValidationRun

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/validate", methods=["POST"])
def validate(self):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am starting Flask using the following three commands:

```
set FLASK_APP=api
set FLASK_DEBUG=1
python -m flask run
```

Comment: Please show how you are starting your Flask app, and the contents of api.py.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've updated the question. I encounter the errors when going to localhost:5000.

Comment: And what directory are you in when you run those commands?

Comment: src/validation-api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Daniel-Roseman, I've figured out what's going on. I changed the `FLASK_APP` environment variable to `validation-api.api`, and ran the `python -m flask run` command from `src`. All imports are working now!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a simple app

```
src/
    app.py
    something.py
    templates/
```

and `app.py` has the statement `import something` in it, then make sure you do NOT have an `__init__.py` in the source directory.

See [the doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/patterns/packages/) for some explanation as to why.